# How do I echo one to many relationships using PHP and Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am currently using Zend Framework 2 and was wondering how I echo a one to many relationship?  Using the Album example I have another table that includes band members (each album can have multiple members)  I am using two queries for this exercise.  One that selects all the albums and one that selects all albums band members.  I don't want to duplicate the album but want the album to echo once and the list of band members to reside next to it.  Many Thanks!

**Album For Each**

```
<?php foreach ($albums as $albumd) : ?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($albumd->title);?></td>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($albumd->artist);?></td>
```

**Artist For Each**

```
<?php foreach ($bandmembers as $member) : ?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($member->firstname);?></td>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($member->lastname);?></td>
```

It works when they are separate but how to I embed one for each in another (is this the best way)?  I would like my results to print similar to below.  I would like to also add other relationships (such as genere) using a similar method.  When I try to embed now I get a rewind error.

```
Album: Dark Side Of The Moon
Artist: Pink Floyd 
     Members:  Roger Waters
     Members:  David Gilmour
     Members:  Richard Wright
     Members:  Nick Mason

Album: Working Mans Dead
Artist: Grateful Dead
     Members:  Jerry Garcia
     Members:  Bob Weir
     Members:  Phil Lesh
     Members:  Bill Kreutzmann
```

**Current View Below:**

```
 <?php foreach ($albums as $albumd) : ?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($albumd->title);?></td>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($albumd->artist);?></td>
      <?php foreach ($artist as $member) : ?>
     <tr> <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($member->artist_first);?></td>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
     <td>
         <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album',
             array('action'=>'edit', 'id' => $albumd->id));?>">Edit</a>
         <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album',
             array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $albumd->id));?>">Delete</a>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with with you have?

Comment: I have updated the question.  I am getting a rewind error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, `$artist` can't be correct. You're passing a list of albums to the view (so far so good) but `$artist` needs to change for each iteration of the album loop, and it's not. Instead of making `$artist` an array that you pre-build in the controller, I would recommend creating a getArtists() method on the Album object, and then calling that in the view. Something like this:

```
foreach ($albums as $album) {
    // print album stuff
    foreach ($album->getArtists() as $artist) {
        // print artist stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I have to move my related controller items to the view?     $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');      
         $artist = new SearchQuery($dbAdapter);
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
            'artists' =>$artist->getArtist()
         ));

Comment: Nope, shouldn't have to. Just put your list of album objects in `$albums` and send that to the view. You should be able to call on all the methods of the object from within the view.

Comment: Do I need to pass a variable in the getArtists() function? getArtists($album)?  I want to query them all from the database though.  It is currently echoing all artist after each album.

Comment: Not if you make getArtists() a method on the Album object, because it would already know what album it's referencing via the $this handle.

Comment: How would I go about this?  Currently I have a SearchQuery class with all my sql statements.      public function getArtist()
    {
        $adapter = $this->getAdapter();
        
        $sql = new Sql($adapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->from('artist');  
        $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
        $resultSet = $adapter->query($selectString, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
        return $resultSet;  
    }

Comment: It seems like I want to apply the adapter design pattern?  I am a little confused on how I go about implementing this.  Can this method handle multiple joins?  Below is an article I found on the subject.  http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/Adapter/php

Comment: foreach ($albums->getArtist($album->id) as $member):  This gives me what I want however it produces a lot of queries (queries the db for each album).

Comment: Set up a data mapper model using... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277173/how-to-use-a-data-mapper-with-sql-queries.  I am now able to echo one to many relationships as stated above.